# Ways to save django model using nested dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-models

I'll try to make this as simple as I can:

**I have 2 models**

```
from django.db import models


class OrderDetail(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Order(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    loaded_info = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    details = models.OneToOneField(OrderDetail)
```

**And I whish to save using a dict like this:**

```
data = {
    "order": {
        "url": "http://stackoverflow.com/",
        "loaded_info": True,
        "status": "complete",
        "details": {
            "product": "Fresh answer",
            "price": "50 points"
        }
    }
}
```

**I'd like to do something close to:**

```
order = Order(**data).save()
```

And get `Order` and `OrderDetail` saved using a single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/serialization/

In this case, you would do something like:

```
qs = Order.objects.select_related('details').get(pk=1)
data = serializers.serialize("json", qs)
```

Comment: Yes, generate json using serializers are good for outputing data, but I want to save data to Order and OrderDetail by just inputing a dictionary into Order model.

Comment: Ok, I understand.  In that case. I think you have the right idea when you say Order(**data).save() . You would have to overwrite init to check of keyword arguments are valid -- but that is what a Form does.  Can you use an OrderForm ?